# Searching for a literal hyphen in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to split a multipage word document into single pages and then deleting all the pages I don't need. The problem is I am copying the text and searching for a pattern and the hyphen is throwing me off. This is the relevant code. If I remove the hyphen and just search for "Order Number", it works but it comes back with two pages instead of just the one I want with the pattern "Order Number -". I have tried a lot of configurations, escaping the hypen `-, --%, etc but nothing works, everything I run that includes the hyphen just outputs 8 DeleteMe pages, instead of 1 Docuemnt and 7 DeleteMe

```
    $Pattern = "Order Number -"
    $rngPg.End = $word.Selection.Start
    $rngPg.Copy()
    #Get Name 
    $regex = [Regex]::Match($rngPg.Text, $Pattern) 
    if($regex.Success)
    {
    $id = "Document" + $i 
    }
    else
    {
    $id = "DeleteMe_" + $i 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your pattern to:

```
$Pattern = 'Order Number [\u2010-\u2015-]'
```

---

#### Explanation:

Word has an [AutoFormat feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatic-formatting-195c72fc-5e3f-43d5-a0c3-bf3606e2e58e) that loves to automagically turn hyphens into dashes - that may be the case here.

English language Office turns hyphens into unicode characters with the codepoint value `0x2013`, but it may vary depending on locale and installed language packs, thus the character set from `0x2010` to `0x2015` + `-`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the help. I would have been lost for a long time on this one.

Comment: @Nolemonkey Happy to help :-) If my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left